# Select Random 20 rows from database table where id = (some id)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to run query that returns random 20 rows from database `where id = some id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are You using MS SQL ?
You can just use query:

```
SELECT TOP 20 column FROM table WHERE id = some_id
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

http://www.petefreitag.com/item/466.cfm

Comment: Vivek wants **random** 20 rows, why add   ORDEER BY   to the query?

Comment: @marlan because `order by newid()` generates a new GUID for each record returned by the query and sorts by that - and because GUIDs are (somewhat) random, you'll get random ordering.

Comment: but is does not satiesfid where condition

Comment: i want query with help option